# How to handle the http response from an api call efficiently using spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, web-applications

When we fire an api call to a 3rd party service, we can get different HTTP responses (200, 404 etc.). How can we handle them in a standard way?

```
private ResponseEntity<ResultHolder> responseEntity;
public ResponseEntity<ResultHolder> serviceTest(String searchText, String countryCode) {
        
        logger.info("Service started");
        String url = prepareUrl(searchText,countryCode); //custom method
        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        prepareHeader(header); //custom method
        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(header);
        try {
            logger.info("Calling the API");
            responseEntity = restClient.exchange(url,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    requestEntity,
                    ResultHolder.class);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception while calling the API "+ e);

            //Here I am trying to get the value of response code and handle based on that
            //Is this the right way to solve the problem?
            if(responseEntity.getStatusCodeValue() != 200) {
                responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<ResultHolder>( 
                      HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        }
        logger.info("Service Ended");
        return responseEntity;
        
    }
```

What if I want to display distinct custom messages for server side errors and for user errors like 'No Internet Connection'.

Kindly help me to understand the good practises in this area.
Thank you

Comment: `if (...){} elseif (...){} else {}`

Comment: Where is instantiate `responseEntity` ?

Comment: I will update the code area with the instantiation too.. @Zorglube

Comment: Ok, what will happend if you have two method, called by two client, modifying `responseEntity` in the same time ? Will you give the same answer to the two client ?

Comment: Ohh.. you are right.. So we have to declare ResponseEntity always inside the method. Am I correct? @Zorglube

Comment: I can't say, the anwser depend on your requierments.